# Issue in DateTime conversion to local Time

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone

I am facing issue in Android with DateTime conversion to local Time with timezone. I am using the below method to convert to local time but i get the 'Year' and 'Time' wrong.

**P.S** The DateTime received is in **Bangladesh Standard Time "Asia/Dhaka", "(GMT +06:00) Dhaka"**

```
public String localToGMT(String serverDate) {
    String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM";//15.06.18 6:00
    String strDate = "";
    ///Date date = new Date();
    try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date gmt = null;

        gmt = sdf.parse(serverDate);
        strDate = sdf.format(gmt);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strDate;
}
```

---

Input : 22.06.2018 00:00

My output  : 22.06.2017 00:12

---

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: mm is minute. MM is month

Comment: I tried the above, then I get  22.12.2017 00:12 :|

Comment: use this sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Comment: use String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: How is it misleading, I added a date format in comment for myself and others to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MM` stands for month, `mm` stands for `minutes`, and you need re-set the timezone, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String serverDate = "22.06.2018 16:00";
    String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm";
    String strDate;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka"));
    Date gmt = sdf.parse(serverDate);

    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    strDate = sdf.format(gmt);
    System.out.println(strDate); // 22.06.2018 10:00
}
```